# Force password entry before each GitHub push in VS Code on macOS

Tags: macos, github, visual-studio-code

How can I force VS Code to ask for my macOS Keychain password before each push to GitHub?

VS Code never asked for my GitHub password (via Keychain) until I pushed to GitHub and it asked before each push again.

This was working until a few hours ago when I had some issues and revoked my access and VS Code requested a new token.

Now VS Code does not ask at all for a password. Even when I remove VS Code from the Keychain whitelist, it asks for my password at program start only once and then not again, even not for pushes.

I want VS Code to request my GitHub token before each push from Keychain again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After comparing my current macOS login Keychain with one from a Backup where everything was still working as I wanted, I found a solution:

There seem to be at least two ways of how VS Code accesses the Keychain:

1. Directly via `OAuth`. This is used when VS Code automatically requests an access token via the GitHub website. It stores the token in the Keychain with the name `vscodevscode.github-authentication`.
2. Indirectly via `git-credential-osxkeychain` and a [personal access token](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token) that is stored in the Keychain with the name `github.com`.

VS Code seems to decide automatically which way it uses depending on which keys it finds in the macOS Keychain.

I have not found a way how to force VS Code to ask for the Keychain password on each push when using `OAuth`, but it is working via `git-credential-osxkeychain` now.

### Solution

1. Request a personal access token via [GitHub / Settings / Developer settings / Personal access tokens](https://github.com/settings/tokens)
2. Retreive your GitHub ID via: `https://api.github.com/users/<your user name>`
3. Open `Keychain Access` and create a new password item:
   Keychain Item Name: `https://github.com`
   Account Name: `<your GitHub ID>`
   Password: `<your personal access token>`

**Notes:**

1. If VS Code asks for your Keychain password multiple times, try a push via command line

   - click on `Always Allow` on the request that asks to `...access key "github.com"...`
   - click on `Allow` on the request that asks to `...use your confidential information stored in "github.com"`.
2. This is a complete "try and error" solution, I have not found much information about that. It would be great if someone could explain what is actually going on here. I have also not found any official information about setting up VS Code via `git-credential-osxkeychain`.
3. I guess `git` needs to be installed to make that work. I installed it via [Homebrew](https://brew.sh)
4. At least for me this solution works for pushing via *VS Code GUI*, *VS Code integrated terminal* and *OS terminal*.

Comment: The Always worked is what solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `git config --global credential.helper`: it references the program in charge of caching your credentials.

A `git config --global --unset credential.helper` would remove it, forcing Git to always ask for your credentials.

Comment: After that VS Code asks for username AND password. That means I have to create a personal access token and remember that (password manager) and enter it each time. I want VS Code to use macOS Keychain and just ask for my Keychain password. That worked before so it should be possible somehow.

Comment: Actually `git config --global --unset credential.helper` has no influence on the VS Code behaviour at all. I was mistaken, because I removed my token from the Keychain. So after setting up a new token, VS Code just pushes without asking for a password even after executing `git config --global --unset credential.helper` again.

Comment: @Toxiro OK so the issue is not with the credential helper but with the Keychain itself which, when queried by VSCode, does no longer require its own Keychain password

Comment: After trying a lot today, I think it is VS Code that is just caching the password instead of asking Keychain on each request. At least when using `OAuth`. I have found a solution now though (see my answer).